# Ошибка NumberFormatException при использовании try-catch

Tags: kotlin, try-catch

Не могли бы вы объяснить мне, почему при использовании функции try-catch она не выявляет ошибку?

```kotlin
fun main() {
    convertStringToDouble(input = readLine()!!)
}

fun convertStringToDouble(input: String): Double {
    try {
        println(input.toDouble())
    } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
        println("0.0")
    }
    return input.toDouble()
}
```

Логи:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "b"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2054)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.math.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.base/java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:556)
    at OneoneKt.convertStringToDouble(oneone.kt:11)
    at OneoneKt.main(oneone.kt:2)
    at OneoneKt.main(oneone.kt)
```

Comment: Тут вопросы принято задавать на русском, переведите его, либо задайте на англоязычном https://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Вы делаете `input.toDouble()`, ловите ошибку. А потом снова делаете `input.toDouble()` и падаете. Второй вызов у вас в try-catch не обернут.

Comment: @Vadik в задании написано что я должен принимать значение цифры в Double , а  если там String должен выводить 0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый вызов вы обернули в try-catch, а второй нет. Поправить можно, например, так:

```kotlin
fun convertStringToDouble(input: String): Double =
    try {
        input.toDouble()
    } catch (exception: NumberFormatException) {
        0.0
    }
```

Более того, можно обойтись без try-catch, воспользоваться функцией `toDoubleOrNull`:

```kotlin
fun convertStringToDouble(input: String): Double =
    input.toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
```

Или, еще более локанично, сделать экстеншен-функцию и назвать ее `toDoubleOrZero`:

```kotlin
fun String.toDoubleOrZero() = toDoubleOrNull() ?: 0.0
```

Comment: cпасибо я понял свою ошибку